# Pandas: Cumulative sum within group with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a DataFrame that looks like this table:

| index | x | y | value_1 | cumsum_1 | cumsum_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 1 | 12 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | 1.2 | 1 | 10 | 12 | 10 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 1 | 7 | 19 | 10 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 0.72 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 5 | 1.5 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 13 |

So my aim is to calculate the cumulative sum of `value_1`. But there are two conditions that must be taken into account.

- First: If value `x` is less than 1 the `cumsum()` is written in column `cumsum_1` and if `x` is greater in column `cumsum_2`.
- Second: column `y` indicates groups (1,2,3,...). When the value in `y` changes, the `cumsum()`-operation start all over again. I think the `grouby()` method would help.

Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: can you show expected output to make it more clear ?

Comment: The expectet output is shown in column ```cumsum_1``` and ```cumsum_2```.

Comment: Hints: (1) `df['x'] < 1` gives you a column of booleans, (2) multiplying this column by `df['value_1']` gives you just the values where `df['x']` is less than 1, and 0 elsewhere, (3) take the `cumsum` of this column, (4) repeat for values that are no less than 1.  This solves the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) on conditions `x` < 1 or `x` >= 1 to temporarily modify the values of `value_1` to 0 according to the condition and then groupby cumsum, as follows:

The second condition is catered by the `.groupby` function while the first condition is catered by the [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)  function, detailed below:

[`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) keeps the column values when the condition is true and change the values (to 0 in this case) when the condition is false.  Thus, for the first condition where column `x` < 1, `value_1` will keep its values for feeding to the subsequent `cumsum` step to accumulate the filtered values of `value_1`.  For rows where the condition `x` < 1 is False, `value_1` has its values masked to 0.  These 0 passed to `cumsum` for accumulation is effectively the same effect as taking out the original values of `value_1` for the accumulation into
column `cumsum_1`.

The second line of codes accumulates `value_1` values to column `cumsum_2` with the opposite condition of `x` >= 1.  These 2 lines of codes, in effect, allocate `value_1` to `cumsum_1` and `cumsum_2` according to `x` < 1 and `x` >= 1, respectively.

(Thanks for the suggestion of @tdy to simplify the codes)

```
df['cumsum_1'] = df['value_1'].where(df['x'] < 1, 0).groupby(df['y']).cumsum()
df['cumsum_2'] = df['value_1'].where(df['x'] >= 1, 0).groupby(df['y']).cumsum()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

      x  y  value_1  cumsum_1  cumsum_2
0  0.10  1       12        12         0
1  1.20  1       10        12        10
2  0.25  1        7        19        10
3  1.00  2        3         0         3
4  0.72  2        5         5         3
5  1.50  2       10         5        13
```

Comment: +1, but can avoid the intermediate columns via `Series.where`, e.g. `df['cumsum_1'] = df.value_1.where(df.x < 1, 0).groupby(df.y).cumsum()`

Comment: @tdy   Oh, yes!  Thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using a pivot:

```
(df.assign(ge1=df['x'].ge(1).map({True: 'cumsum_2', False: 'cumsum_1'}))
   .pivot(columns='ge1', values='value_1').fillna(0).groupby(df['y']).cumsum()
   .astype(int)
)
```

output:

```
ge1  cumsum_1  cumsum_2
0          12         0
1          12        10
2          19        10
3           0         3
4           5         3
5           5        13
```

full code:

```
df[['cumsum_1', 'cumsum_2']] = (df.assign(ge1=df['x'].ge(1).map({True: 'cumsum_2', False: 'cumsum_1'}))
                                  .pivot(columns='ge1', values='value_1').fillna(0).groupby(df['y']).cumsum()
                                  .astype(int)
                                )
```

(or use `pd.concat` to concatenate)

output:

```
   index     x  y  value_1  cumsum_1  cumsum_2
0      0  0.10  1       12        12         0
1      1  1.20  1       10        12        10
2      2  0.25  1        7        19        10
3      3  1.00  2        3         0         3
4      4  0.72  2        5         5         3
5      5  1.50  2       10         5        13
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above approaches but a little more chained.

```
df[['cumsum_1a', 'cumsum2a']] = (df.
 assign(
    v1 = lambda temp: temp.x >= 1,
    v2 = lambda temp: temp.v1 * temp.value_1,
    v3 = lambda temp: ~ temp.v1 * temp.value_1
    ).
 groupby('y')[['v2', 'v3']].
 cumsum()
 )
```